# Why my while loop makes one more execution after it hits break?

Tags: python

I am still learning how to write a proper while loop. This mini exercise asks to write a while loop that finds the largest square number less than an integer limit and stores it in a variable called nearest_square. A square number is the product of an integer multiplied by itself. For example, 36 is a square number because it equals 6*6. If the limit is set to 40, your code should set the nearest_square to 36.

So I first wrote the code like this:

```
limit = 40

n=1
nearest_square = 1

while nearest_square < limit:
    nearest_square = n**2
    n += 1
    
print(nearest_square)
```

The output is:

```
49
```

I don't know why n didn't break at 6 but 7.

I did edit my code slightly, and this time it breaks at 6.

```
limit = 40

n=1
nearest_square = 1

while n**2 < limit:
    nearest_square = n**2
    n += 1
    
print(nearest_square)
```

Output is 36 this time.

I don't know when the while loop breaks and why in the first code block, n ends at 7 and goes back to the loop again and calculate the nearest_square at 49 even though 49 is already larger than 40.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know why n didn't break at 6 but 7

Let's manually iterate from `n=6`,

## n = 6

```
while nearest_square < limit:  ## 25 < 40 (25, nearest_square calculated when n=5)
    nearest_square = n**2  ## nearest_square = 6**2 => 36
    n += 1  ## n =7
```

## n = 7

```
while nearest_square < limit:  ## 36 < 40 (36, nearest_square calculated when n=6)
        nearest_square = n**2  ## nearest_square = 7**2 => 49
        n += 1  ## n = 8
```

## n = 8

```
while nearest_square < limit:  ## 49 < 40 (49, nearest_square calculated when n=7) 
       exit ## since condition is not met
```

In first case, you are checking the `nearest_square` of previous `n`, not the current `n`

As mentioned by @tdelaney, you could add an `if` inside the `while` as well.

Comment: wow, thank you so much! You are really thinking like a computer now. :)

Comment: Welcome! Beep beep boop. You can try http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit for visualizing the flow, really helpful

Comment: OMG, I love it. Already bookmarked it. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In your first case, `nearest_square` is checked to see whether the `while` loop should continue, but it's only updated in the next iteration of the `while` loop after `n` has been incremented, so after `n` gets to 7, the program checks the value of `nearest_square`, finds that it's still 36 because the program hasn't updated it yet, and so changes `nearest_square` to 49 and `n` to 8 before stopping. In your second case, your program checks whether `n*n>40` before changing the value of `nearest_square`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I did check the answer. The smart way is to define nearest_square = n**2 out of the while loop. May stop it from updating.

Comment: @Yi.D To do this you'll want to define `nearest_square` as a function, like `def nearest_square(): return n**2`. Integer variables don't change even if what was used to calculate them does; the only variables that work like that are objects that contain references to other variables; e.g. if a list includes an object as an element, then if an attribute of that object changes, looking it up using the list will return the changed value, because the list contains a reference to rather than a copy of the object. That's not true for numbers, strings, or other simple data types.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the first loop is that you break after you've gone over the limit. you've got the 49 when you really wanted the calculation right before it. You either need to keep the previous value or do the calculation twice like your second example. Since its an inexpensive calculation, either is fine. But more generally tracking the previous value is more common.

Since your count can be handled by `range`, this can be a `for` loop.

```
limit = 40
nearest_square = 1

for n in range(1, 40):
    next_square = n**2
    if next_square >= limit:
        break
    nearest_square = next_square    
print(nearest_square)
```

Comment: Yes, I prefer for loop if I can use it.  For loop is way easier to do and each step is quite crystal clear. I seldom use while loop. First for the possible infinite loop and second it is hard for me to visualize how the computer is doing in the back.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that, in the first loop, `nearest_square` still corresponds to `6**2` although `n=7` when `while` is deciding if the block should be executed again. Note that you increase the value of `n` after storing `n**2` in `nearest_square`.

Changes in one variable don't automatically transfer to other variables that were created using previous calls.

These kinds of "off by one" issues with `while` loops can be pretty hard to catch, so don't feel too discouraged!

Answer (score 0):

That happens because first it checks it and only then does it square it.

When you changed it to become:

```
limit = 40

n=1
nearest_square = 1

while n**2 < limit:
    nearest_square = n**2
    n += 1
    
print(nearest_square)
```

It checks the squared sum before you actually square it.

Another solution to it would have been:

```
n=1

while (n + 1) ** 2 < limit:
    n += 1
    
print(n ** 2)
```

Nice problem solving :)